# Using post method in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I want to create a function use the **AJAX** but when I use the **POST** method to send the information the function don't work but the **GET** method is **working**
This is my [function](https://jsfiddle.net/je376tkL/):

```
function ajax(page,method,id,send,a){
    a = a || true;
    page = page || '';
    method = method || 'GET';
    id = id || '';
    send = send || '';
    
    if(page!='' || id!=''){
    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     if(!xmlhttp)
   xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Mmxl2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
   if(!xmlhttp)
   xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Mmxl2.XMLHTTP.6.0");
    
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readystate == 4 || xmlhttp.status == 200)
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        };
        
    if(send!=''){
    if(method=='get' || method=='GET'){
     xmlhttp.open("GET",page+'?'+send,a);
     xmlhttp.send();
    }
   else if(method=='post' || method=='POST'){
     xmlhttp.open('POST',page,a);
     xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader('Conect-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
     xhttp.send(send);
    }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: please define "don't work". What errors do you get? And why is this tagged with PHP? It's a Javascript function.

Comment: Post your code here !!

Answer (score 1):

Please paste in your question the content of your fiddle, as links can go down.
What is wrong for me in your code is this line :

```
xmlhttp.SetRequestHeader('Conect-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

`'Conect-Type'` should be replaced by `'Content-Type'`.

Comment: I replace it but no change I use the function like that's ajax('jax.php','post','jax','name=mohamad&age=14',true)"

Comment: I correct it but no change I use the function like that's 
ajax('jax.php','post','jax','name=mohamad&age=14',true)"

Comment: @Firstdev we would need more informations then. What is the Http Status of the request once it is sent ? Have you checked the access.log of your server to see how it is reached ? Don't you have specific server-side directives to forbid POST requests ?

Comment: I was try it in a local server in my tablet "bit web server app"
I'm not professional developer
Can you give me a function use the post method just for try if the problem is in my code or in other something

Comment: @Firstdev well you could start by opening the dev tools of your browsers, go to the "Network" tab and check for your request status, response, headers, etc. 
For Chrome : https://developer.chrome.com/devtools
For Firefox : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Opening_the_Web_Console

Answer (score 1):

you could just use the already made jquery ajax calls for post and get

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

```
$.get( "test.cgi", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } )
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });
```

Comment: I don't want to use jQuery

Comment: I don't want use jQuery

Comment: @Firstdev you shouldnt had put jquery in as a tag then. I see its removed now